# how to load a pdf from server as an aspx page (or loading pdf files securely)?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, pdf

I have a folder with pdfs, but I don't want them to be public (like just typing www.domain.com/pdfs/doc.pdf).

I need them to have a security measure of some sorts (like www.domain.com/loadpdf.asmx?key=23452ADFASD12345 or using POST)

How do I do this?, ive found out how to create a pdf, but not how to load one from server.

thanks.

Comment: you don't want the file names known?

Comment: No need to allow the user to know too much about how you store your PDFs!

Comment: maybe it would be good to show the file name if they choose to save the pdf... I didn't thougth about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the PDF into a byte array and use that.  As awright18 said, do this in a handler (.ashx).  Something like this:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class MapHandler : IHttpHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
{

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        CreateImage(context);
    }

    private void CreateImage(HttpContext context) {

        string documentFullname = // Get full name of the PDF you want to display...

        if (File.Exists(documentFullname)) {

            byte[] buffer;

            using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(documentFullname, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream)) {
                buffer = reader.ReadBytes((int)reader.BaseStream.Length);
            }

            context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString());
            context.Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
            context.Response.End();

        } else {
            context.Response.Write("Unable to find the document you requested.");
        }
    }

    public bool IsReusable {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223654/can-i-display-a-pdf-but-not-allow-linking-to-it-in-a-website) here at SO useful, but the above should work for you.

Comment: cool thank you, just one question, will this preserve the filename if the user chooses to save the file?

Comment: Glad to help.  No, it doesn't preserve the filename.  It appears that the class name of the handler is the default filename.  I plan to see if I can change the default filename to something more meaningful.  If you find a way to do this (or if someone out there knows) please post!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a custom http handler to handle those requests. [Here](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article112.aspx) is an article the covers your exact question.